# Application Permission in Blackberry 9700 & 9300 not appearing

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an application where I am recording voice and storing the recording in file:///home/. For this purpose, when i click on record button, it asks for a permission

Application Permission 
The application has requested to record

Allow  Deny

On clicking Allow, it asks for following permission :

Application Permission 
The application has requested a file connection to listenn to messages
Do not ask for file
Do not ask for file to listen to messages
Allow Deny

On hitting allow, it begins recording and simultaneously saves the recording in SDCard.This works fine in 9250 Storm.

But when I am testing the same app in 9700 & 9300 it asks only for recording permission and not for file saving, thus not saving my file. Am I missing some settings in phone??

Answer (score 0):

You may ask for the requested permissions explicitly gain it before entering the process.

here is a code sample to do this

```
ApplicationPermissionsManager manager = ApplicationPermissionsManager.getInstance();
            int current = manager.getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_FILE_API);
                if (current != ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW) {
                    ApplicationPermissions permissions = new ApplicationPermissions();
                    permissions.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_FILE_API);
                    manager.invokePermissionsRequest(permissions);
                }
```

Comment: Sounds like this might work. Will give it a shot anyways. Thanks buddy